# How to do I stop a while loop if my list doesn't have anything in it

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

I have a list which each round deleted something in it. How do I stop this while loop after the list runs out of things in it?

```
while (list has something in it):
```

Comment: `while len(list)>0: do_stuff()`

Comment: @Cut7er `while list:`